# Display saved EditText from MainActivity in a Fragment with SharedPreferences

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I am saving a EditText to SharedPreferences but I am not able to see in my Fragment the saved text.
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and by the way I use SharedPreferences for my apk.

This is my code of saving data in MainActivity.

```
public static final String Save_Search = "Save_Search";
public EditText searchPlugin;
public String textForSearch;


searchPlugin = findViewById(R.id.etSearch);


public void saveData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Save_Search, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(editText, searchPlugin.getText().toString());  editor.putString(Save_Search, searchPlugin.getText().toString());
    Log.d("Test", searchPlugin.getText().toString());
//This is saving me the typed text.
}

public void updateView() {
        searchPlugin.setText(textForSearch);
    }
```

This is the layout of EditText

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/etSearch" android:imeOptions="actionGo|flagNoExtractUi" style="@style/SearchEditText.MainSearch" />
```

This is the Fragment

```
  public class FragmentHistory extends Fragment {
    View paramView;
    TextView textView;
    public FragmentHistory() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        paramView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_item, container, false);
        textView = paramView.findViewById(R.id.tvHistoryName);
        SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String text = pref.getString("Save_Search", "");
        textView.setText(text);
        return paramView;
    }


}
```

This is the history layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_home"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:id="@id/ivHistory" style="@style/ivHistory" />
    <TextView android:id="@id/tvHistoryName" android:layout_height="38dp" style="@style/TextViewQuery"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@id/imgViewSetQuery" style="@style/ImageViewSetQuery" />
    <TextView android:textSize="@dimen/search_font" android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center" android:id="@id/btnDelete" android:background="@color/red" android:paddingLeft="5.0dip"
        android:paddingRight="5.0dip" android:visibility="gone" android:longClickable="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="@string/Delete" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What are you seeing when debugging your program when saving the contents of the edit text?

Comment: You are thinking in Main Activity ?

Comment: I am thinking in general, why does your application crash? Because of a null pointer exception? Edit your post and give us the exact error.

Comment: For the moment it is not telling any error and in the log it is showing that the edittext is saved but in the Fragment it is not displayed.
I will edit the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to save the data by the "Save_Search" key, but you are saving your data
under the key "editText"

**Replace this line:**

```
 editor.putString(editText, searchPlugin.getText().toString());
```

**With this line**

```
editor.putString(Save_Search, searchPlugin.getText().toString());
```

Comment: I tried this and It is saving the editText but it is not showing in the Fragment.

Comment: Yep the text what I have writed in the MainActivity.
See I have updated the code.

Comment: and when your app crashes, what is the error that shown in the logcat?

Comment: Now the app it is not crashing it works but not displaying the `editText`

Comment: ok, now , try to print the text to the console and tell me if you are printing the correct text

Comment: in the MainActivity it tells me the correct text but in the Fragment it is not telling me anything.
If I write `Log.d("Test", "Test");` it is telling me this log.
But if I write `Log.d("Test", text);` it is not telling nothing.

Comment: and are you sure that you are printing the string in the right place?(your code might be good with no problems but you are not calling a method )looks like you are on the right road - just debug your code a few times and i am sure that you will find that went wrong

Comment: I will try to see xml maybe it is something that is not showing me in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Replace :

```
SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

With:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Save_Search", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

in your fragment